# Issue configuring redis cluster with TLS

Tags: ssl, redis, redis-cluster

I'm trying to setup a redis cluster using redis 6.0.10 compiled with TLS support. This is part of config related to TLS and cluster :

```
port 0
tls-port 6390
tls-cert-file /usr/local/redis6/tls/redisTLS.pem
tls-key-file /usr/local/redis6/tls/redis.key
tls-ca-cert-file /usr/local/redis6/tls/redistlschain.crt
tls-replication yes
tls-cluster yes
tls-auth-clients no
cluster-enabled yes
```

also i'm using requirepass option. I have 3 nodes each has 2 instances. Each has similar config with the same certs and key.
When i try to create a cluster with following command:

`/usr/local/redis6/bin/redis-cli --tls --cert /usr/local/redis6/tls/redisTLS.pem --key /usr/local/redis6/tls/redis.key  --cacert /usr/local/redis6/tls/redistlschain.crt -a somepass -p 6390 --cluster create 10.1.22.11:6390 10.1.22.11:6391 10.1.22.12:6390 10.1.22.12:6391 10.1.22.13:6390 10.1.22.13:6391 --cluster-replicas 1`

it stuck on connecting nodes. In the log files i see following errors:

```
Accepting cluster node connection from 10.1.22.11:41398
Error accepting cluster node connection: error:1417C086:SSL routines:tls_process_client_certificate:certificate verify failed
```

It seems like an issue with certificate but when i use those certificates with redis-cli utility or other redis clients they work successfully. I can connect to redis instance and execute commands.
So it's not clear what should be fixed with certificates setup.
Is it something wrong with server certificate ? Or i need a client certificate in addition?
I have an option tls-auth-clients set to "no" so expected that client certificate is not needed ( also docs mention this).
Also do i need to have different server certificate for each node or it's ok to have the same on all nodes?

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: HI, Did you find any solution to your problem? I'm facing the same issue

Comment: Unfortunately not. I'm not using cluster setup with TLS for now.

Comment: Is this self signed cert ?

Comment: yes, it was self-signed